# stacking colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a simple way to form a new colormap by stacking together two existing ones?

What I'm trying to achieve is to make yet another color-coded scatter plot, where the color-mapped variable varies from large negative to large positive values, and I'd like to tone down the values around zero --- basically, I'd like to be able to pick colors from a stock colormap (say, `cm.Blues_r`) for negative values of the color-mapped variable, and from a different one (say, `cm.Oranges`) for positive values of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, but as a first pass I would try making a simple sub-class of `colors.Colormap`.

```
class split_cmap(colors.Colormap):
    def __init__(self, cmap_a, cmap_b, split=.5):
        '''Makes a split color map cmap_a is the low range, 
           cmap_b is the high range
           split is where to break the range
        '''
        self.cmap_a, self.cmap_b = cmap_a, cmap_b
        self.split = split

    def __call__(self, v):
        if v < self.split:
            return self.cmap_a(v) 
            # or you might want to use v / self.split
        else:
            return self.cmap_b(v) 
            # or you might want to use (v - self.split) / (1 - self.split)

    def set_bad(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.cmap_a.set_bad(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cmap_b.set_bad(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_over(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cmap_a.set_over(*args, **kwargs) # not really needed
        self.cmap_b.set_over(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_under(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cmap_a.set_under(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cmap_b.set_under(*args, **kwargs) # not really needed

    def is_gray(self):
        return False
```

[`colors.Colormap` class definition](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html).

You are going to need to dig into the `Normalize` classes as well.  The color maps only know about `[0, 1]`, so you will have to make sure that your `norm` maps to `.5` where you want the change over to happen.

You could probably generalize this to take a list of maps and split points and have as many color maps as you want.  This also needs all manner of sanity checks.

If you re-normalize the input, you could also use this to make a periodic version of *any* existing color map by passing it the color map and it's reversed partner.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler to make the colormap yourself, especially when so few colors are involved. This one is orange-white-blue.

```
cdict = {'red':   [ (0.0,   0.0, 0.0),
                    (0.475, 1.0, 1.0),
                    (0.525, 1.0, 1.0),
                    (1.0,   1.0, 1.0)
                  ],
         'green': [ (0.0,   0.0, 0.0),
                    (0.475, 1.0, 1.0),
                    (0.525, 1.0, 1.0),
                    (1.0,   0.65, 0.0)
                  ],
         'blue':  [ (0.0,   1.0, 1.0),
                    (0.475, 1.0, 1.0),
                    (0.525, 1.0, 1.0),
                    (1.0,   0.0, 0.0)
                  ]
}
rwb_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(name = 'rwb_colormap', colors = cdict, N = 256)
```

A colormap is a dictionary for the RGB values. For each color, a list of tupples gives the different segments. Each segment is a point along the z-axis, ranging from 0 to 1. The colors for the levels is interpolated from these segments.

```
segment z-axis  end      start
i       z[i]    v0[i]    v1[i]
i+1     z[i+1]  v0[i+1]  v1[i+1]   
i+2     z[i+2]  v0[i+2]  v1[i+2]
```

Levels between `z[i]` and `z[i+1]` will have colors between `v1[i]` and `v0[i+1]` etc. This makes it possible to 'jump' colors. `v0[0]` and `v1[-1]` are not used. You can use as many segments as you want. (adapted from here: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap)

`N` is the number of quantization levels. So for `N = 256` it will interpolate the map for 256 levels. I use 256 out of laziness. I guess you have to be careful when you set `N = 6` and you make 4 contours.

The 0.475 and 0.525 are to ensure that the middle contour is truly white. For the levels `[-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5]` the fill is now orange-white-blue. If I had used 0.5 instead the middle level would be an interpolation of blue-ish and orange-ish.

The RGB code for orange is 255-165-0 or 1-0.65-0 if the scale is 0-1.

Comment: Well, I wanted to have was flexibility based on the already existing work, but OK, if we're at it, would you please explain 1) why `0.475` and `0.525`, 2) why 3x4 lists, 3) why `0.65` and 4) why `256`. Can make it a separate question if that'd be an extra incentive.