# matplotlib plot_surface, how to make value/surface intersections show?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using plot_surface to create the following graph

```
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=True, shade=False)
```

[image]

I want to be able to add in some indication of where the z-axis zero-plane  intersects the surface. That is every point on the surface which is Am3+Ae3 = 0 or nearest Am3+Ae3 = 0.

Is there some function that will do this in matplotlib, or perhaps some way to make cmap show a very defined black around that zero value?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit a limitation of matplotlib, it draws in layers so you can't automatically have intersections of surfaces in 3D (yet).  You can fake it by hand (see [How to draw intersecting planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this/14825951#14825951) ) or use `mayavi` from enthought (which is openGL based and does 'real' 3D rendering)

You can definitely do this with color map, but requires a bit of work (see  [stacking colormaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399095/stacking-colormaps/15399564#15399564) ).