# modify discrete LinearSegmentedColormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a climatologist and often plot anomalies of e.g. temperature fields using a "blue-to-white-to-red" colormap. To make the plots more readable, I discretize the colormap in a certain number of levels (bins) with a function which I "found" in the Internet (but I don't really understand it):

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as cols
from numpy.random import randn

def cmap_discretize(cmap, N):
    colors_i = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1., N), (0.,0.,0.,0.)))
    colors_rgba = cmap(colors_i)
    indices = np.linspace(0, 1., N+1)
    cdict = {}
    for ki,key in enumerate(('red','green','blue')):
        cdict[key] = [ (indices[i], colors_rgba[i-1,ki], colors_rgba[i,ki]) for i in xrange(N+1) ]
    # Return colormap object.
    return cols.LinearSegmentedColormap(cmap.name + "_%d"%N, cdict, 1024)



cmap_disc= cmap_discretize(cm.RdBu_r,12)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

cax = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=cmap_disc)
plt.colorbar(cax)

plt.show()
```

This results in

[image]

Now I want to set the two middle-most segments (i.e. those two close to 0) to white because I don't want to show very small deviations.

My goal would be to end up with something similar to this:

[image]

I really have a hard time to figure out how these LinearSegmentedColormap can be modified accordingly. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Please read: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap which has a clear description of how the color maps work.

Comment: And you might get some traction using the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399095/stacking-colormaps/15399564#15399564 and passing in two descritized color maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start by walking through the code you have

```
# get some uniformly sampled data, padded out a bit
colors_i = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1., N), (0.,0.,0.,0.)))
# sample the input colormap at our sample points
colors_rgba = cmap(colors_i)
# indices for color map
indices = np.linspace(0, 1., N+1)
# dict to pass to the LinearSegmentedColormap
cdict = {}
# loop over the colors
for ki,key in enumerate(('red','green','blue')):
    # in each color assemble a list that looks like
    #[...,
    # (indices[2], colors_rgba[1,ki], colors_rgba[2,ki]),
    # (indices[3], colors_rgba[2,ki], colors_rgba[3,ki]),
    # ....]
    cdict[key] = [ (indices[i], colors_rgba[i-1,ki], colors_rgba[i,ki]) for i in xrange(N+1) ]
    # The color for a number between [indices[2], indices[3]] are interpolated
    # between colors_rgba[2,ki] and colors_rgba[2,ki] which are the same
    # which is what gives you the discrete blocks.
# Construct and return colormap object.
return cols.LinearSegmentedColormap(cmap.name + "_%d"%N, cdict, 1024)
```

So now the question is how to create a color map with a 'doubled' white band in the middle.  I would change the function bit to have it take in two color maps (top and bottom)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as cols
from numpy.random import randn

def cmap_double_discretize(cmap_bottom, cmap_top, N, split=.5):
    """
    Generates a descritized color map using two existing color maps

    Parameters
    ----------
    cmap_bottom : cmap
        The bottom cmap

    cmap_top : cmap
        The top cmap

    N : int
       The number of bins in each color map

    split : float, optional
       Where to join the maps, must be in [0, 1]
    """
    # sanity check
    assert split < 1 and split > 0
    # set up the data structure
    cdict = {lab: [] for lab in ('red','green','blue')}
    # do this in a fancy loop to a) save typing, b) make it easy to
    # retrofit to do arbitrary splits
    for cmap, ends in zip((cmap_bottom, cmap_top), ((0, split), (split, 1))):

        # run over the _whole_ range for each color map
        colors_i = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1., N), (0.,0.,0.,0.)))
        # map the color
        colors_rgba = cmap(colors_i)
        # get the values 
        indices = np.linspace(ends[0], ends[1], N+1, endpoint=True)

        for ki,key in enumerate(('red','green','blue')):
            cdict[key].extend((indices[i], colors_rgba[i-1,ki], colors_rgba[i,ki]) for i in xrange(N+1))
            #    print cdict
    # Return colormap object.
    return cols.LinearSegmentedColormap(cmap.name + "_%d"%N, cdict, 1024)

red_cdict = {'red': [(0, 0, 1),
                     (1, 1, 0)],
            'blue': [(0, 0, 0),
                     (1, 1, 0)],
            'green': [(0, 0, 0),
                     (1, 1, 0)]}

blue_cdict = {'blue': [(0, 0, 1),
                       (1, 1, 0),],
            'red': [(0, 0, 1),
                    (1, 0, 0)],
            'green': [(0, 0, 1),
                     (1, 0, 0)]}
red_cmap = cols.LinearSegmentedColormap('red', red_cdict, 1024)
blue_cmap = cols.LinearSegmentedColormap('blue', blue_cdict, 1024)

test_cmap = cmap_double_discretize(red_cmap, blue_cmap, 6)
# these don't actually go to white!
# test_cmap = cmap_double_discretize(cm.get_cmap('Reds_r'), cm.get_cmap('Blues'), 6)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

cax = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=test_cmap)
plt.colorbar(cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can easily modify this to split across more than two color maps.

Comment: this also works, but does not support predefined colormaps with white in the middle (like bwr,seismic,RdBu,RdGy...). Still many thanks for your effort

Answer (score 5):

The function you have found builds a data structure (in `cdict`) for defining a [LinearSegmentedColormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) with segments that don't perform any interpolation (i.e., `y1` in row `i` is always identical to `y0` in row `i+1`, and this gives the constant, or discrete, color "bands").

`cdict` is a weird data structure, a dictionary which contains the keys `'red'`, `'green'` and `'blue'`.  The value for each of these keys is a list structure containing tuples of the form `(x, y0, y1)`.  `x` is the color map coordinate, which is some floating point number between 0 and 1.  `y0` is the color value on the "left" side of `x`, and `y1` is the color value on the "right" side of `x`.  Colors are linearly interpolated in bands between consecutive values of `x`; if the first tuple is given by `(0, A, B)` and the second tuple by `(X, C, D)`, then the color of a point `t` between `0` and `X` will be given by `(t - 0) / (X - 0) * (C - B) + B`.

For your purposes, your function works pretty well, but needs to have the "bands" near the middle of the color map replaced with a white color.  You can try something like the following:

```
def cmap_discretize(cmap, N):
    colors_i = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1., N), (0.,0.,0.,0.)))
    colors_rgba = cmap(colors_i)
    indices = np.linspace(0, 1., N+1)
    cdict = {}
    for ki,key in enumerate(('red','green','blue')):
        cdict[key] = [ (indices[i], colors_rgba[i-1,ki], colors_rgba[i,ki]) for i in xrange(N+1) ]
    # "white out" the bands closest to the middle
    num_middle_bands = 2 - (N % 2)
    middle_band_start_idx = (N - num_middle_bands) // 2
    for middle_band_idx in range(middle_band_start_idx,
                                 middle_band_start_idx + num_middle_bands):
        for key in cdict.keys():
            old = cdict[key][middle_band_idx]
            cdict[key][middle_band_idx] = old[:2] + (1.,)
            old = cdict[key][middle_band_idx + 1]
            cdict[key][middle_band_idx + 1] = old[:1] + (1.,) + old[2:]
    # Return colormap object.
    return cols.LinearSegmentedColormap(cmap.name + "_%d"%N, cdict, 1024)
```

Comment: this is great, but I still need to work it through to understand it

Comment: I'm a little leary of reaching in squashing the colors like this because you are making the color map non-linear in a really non-transparent way.