# How to use two distinct colormaps in different data ranges on a single data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I am trying to plot some simulated data, using a colormap to indicate absolute magnitude, and quiver vector length to indicate relative magnitude of the quantities. What I would like to do is set a threshold value, above which a different colormap will become active, and which can scale based upon the range of data that falls above the threshold.

<strike>For example, in the included image I have managed to combine two builtin colormaps into one, but it is still a linear scale that can only be characterized by its maximum and minimum values. What I would like to do is set a constant value to be the max of the blue-green segment, but the range of values in the yellow-red segment should range from this set constant value, to the maximum value in the data set.</strike>
(Apparently my rep is not high enough to include images, probably making this difficult to understand)

I would also be happy to use two separate color schemes, but I need to find a way to enable each, only within a certain range of data.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399095/stacking-colormaps/15399564#15399564  or use `set_under` and `set_over` to do the plotting twice with the out of range values mapped to `alpha=0`.  Post a link to the image you want, someone with highenough rep can edit it in for you.

Comment: although, the issue here isn't really the color map, its you want a very non-linear normalization function.  You might want to sub-class `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` as well.

Comment: Any code? What have you tried?