# Combining two matplotlib colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to merge two colormaps into one, such that I can use one `cmap` for negative values and the other one for positive values.

At the moment I do it with masked arrays and plotting one image with one `cmap` and the other image with the other, resulting in:

[image]

with the following data

```
dat = np.random.rand(10,10) * 2 - 1
pos = np.ma.masked_array(dat, dat<0)
neg = np.ma.masked_array(dat, dat>=0)
```

I plotted `pos` with `gist_heat_r` and `neg` with `binary`.

I would like to have a single colorbar with the combined `cmap`'s, so this is not the correct approach for me.

So, how do I take two existing `cmaps`'s and merge them into one?

EDIT: I admit, this is a duplicate, but the answer that's given is much more clear here. Also the example images make it more clear.

Comment: Interesting question. But for your case, you would normally use a diverging colormap (two hues, one for positive numbers another for negative ones). your combination of reds and greys is available in `plt.cm.RdGy`. This yields a continuous map around zero. If I'm not mistaken you have a discontinuity at 0. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is not what I want. The positive and negative values mean something else. And to stay coherent in the paper I'm writing, I would like to use the same cmap in all pictures, which it the one for positive values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stacking colormaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399095/stacking-colormaps)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Colormaps are basically just interpolation functions which you can call. They map values from the interval [0,1] to colors. So you can just sample colors from both maps and then combine them:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

data = np.random.rand(10,10) * 2 - 1

# sample the colormaps that you want to use. Use 128 from each so we get 256
# colors in total
colors1 = plt.cm.binary(np.linspace(0., 1, 128))
colors2 = plt.cm.gist_heat_r(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))

# combine them and build a new colormap
colors = np.vstack((colors1, colors2))
mymap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

plt.pcolor(data, cmap=mymap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

**NOTE**: I understand that you might have specific needs for this, but in my opinion this is not a good approach: How will you distinguish -0.1 from 0.9? -0.9 from 0.1?

One way to prevent this is to sample the maps only from ~0.2 to ~0.8 (e.g.: `colors1 = plt.cm.binary(np.linspace(0.2, 0.8, 128))`) so they wont go all the way up to black:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks! Clean solution, perfect!

Comment: Any idea how to do it in a function where the two colors maps names are given as parameters? plt.cm[color_map_name] doesn't seem to to work

Comment: Regarding the worry on same different values mapping to same color. Some times this is desired, such as if your data is an angle. Then 0=2*pi for instance.  In that case to choose colors as `colors1 = plt.cm.gray(np.linspace(0., 1, 128))` and `colors2 = plt.cm.hot_r(np.linspace(0., 1, 128))` makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @NoamPeled use `getattr`. Like such (adding the predefined matplotlib colormap to your list of colormaps to stack): `cmaplist.append(getattr(plt.cm,'coolwarm')(np.linspace(0,1,256,endpoint=False)+0.5/256))`. Note for my purposes I needed some specific endpoint customization to avoid overlaps. ( wanted to have multiple 1-D heatmaps with different colormaps on a single pcolormesh. Here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761430/single-pcolormesh-with-more-than-one-colormap-matplotlib-solved

Comment: This is great. I am trying this approach for a scatter plot, but the colorbar has a strange effect with the split going above 0 ([picture](https://imgur.com/a/tF6QrNs)). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer but in order not to sample just between ~0.2 to ~0.8, you can for example reverse the binary colormap. Here is how to do it.

```
colors1 = plt.cm.binary_r(np.linspace(0., 1, 128))
colors2 = plt.cm.gist_heat_r(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))

colors = np.vstack((colors1, colors2))
mymap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

plt.pcolor(data, cmap=mymap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The main change is replacing `plt.cm.binary` with `plt.cm.binary_r`.