# Python equivalent for Matlab's Demcmap (elevation +/- appropriate colormap)

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, colormap, topography

I am looking for a way to get an elevation appropriate colormap for `matplotlib`.

the cmap '`terrain`' looks great but the colorscaling isn't based around zero (i.e. if the scale is 0->5000m, the 0->1000m range may be shades of blue, which you would assume to be for below sea-level)

for example:
[image]

The Matlab function equivalent is:
[`demcmap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/demcmap.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

What is the best way to get matplotlib to shift a terrain colormap's greens/browns and blues around the zero elevation mark?

Comment: How should the matplotlib colormap know which data value in your plot belongs to the sea level?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sea level is 0m, thus why I said to shift the colormap around the zero elevation map

Comment: Newer matplotlib docs seem to cover this topic: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#twoslopenorm-different-mapping-on-either-side-of-a-center

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunaly, matplotlib does not provide the functionality of Matlab's `demcmap`.
There might actually be some build-in features in the python `basemap` package, of which I'm not aware.

So, sticking to matplotlib on-board options, we can subclass [`Normalize`](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) to build a color normalization centered around a point in the middle of the colormap. This technique can be found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib) on StackOverflow and adapted to the specific needs, namely to set a `sealevel` (which is probably best chosen as `0`) and the value in the colormap `col_val` (ranging between 0 and 1) to which this sealevel should correspond. In the case of the terrain map, it seems that `0.22`, corresponding to a turqoise color, might be a good choice.
The Normalize instance can then be given as an argument to `imshow`. The resulting figures can be seen down below in the first row of the picture.

Due to the smooth transition around the sealevel the values around `0` appear in a turqoise color, making it hard to distinguish between land and sea.
We can therefore change the terrain map a bit and cut out those colors, such that the coastline is better visible. This is done by [combining two parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051488/combining-two-matplotlib-colormaps) of the map, ranging from 0 to 0.17 and from 0.25 to 1, and thus cutting out a part of it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

class FixPointNormalize(matplotlib.colors.Normalize):
    """ 
    Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144529/shifted-colorbar-matplotlib
    Subclassing Normalize to obtain a colormap with a fixpoint 
    somewhere in the middle of the colormap.

    This may be useful for a `terrain` map, to set the "sea level" 
    to a color in the blue/turquise range. 
    """
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, sealevel=0, col_val = 0.21875, clip=False):
        # sealevel is the fix point of the colormap (in data units)
        self.sealevel = sealevel
        # col_val is the color value in the range [0,1] that should represent the sealevel.
        self.col_val = col_val
        matplotlib.colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.sealevel, self.vmax], [0, self.col_val, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))

# Combine the lower and upper range of the terrain colormap with a gap in the middle
# to let the coastline appear more prominently.
# inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051488/combining-two-matplotlib-colormaps
colors_undersea = plt.cm.terrain(np.linspace(0, 0.17, 56))
colors_land = plt.cm.terrain(np.linspace(0.25, 1, 200))
# combine them and build a new colormap
colors = np.vstack((colors_undersea, colors_land))
cut_terrain_map = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('cut_terrain', colors)



# invent some data (height in meters relative to sea level)
data = np.linspace(-1000,2400,15**2).reshape((15,15))


# plot example data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols=3, figsize=(11,6) )
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.92, hspace = 0.28, wspace = 0.15)

plt.figtext(.5, 0.95, "Using 'terrain' and FixedPointNormalize", ha="center", size=14)
norm = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0, vmax=3400)
im = ax[0,0].imshow(data+1000, norm=norm, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[0,0])

norm2 = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0, vmax=3400)
im2 = ax[0,1].imshow(data, norm=norm2, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax[0,1])

norm3 = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0, vmax=0)
im3 = ax[0,2].imshow(data-2400.1, norm=norm3, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)
fig.colorbar(im3, ax=ax[0,2])

plt.figtext(.5, 0.46, "Using custom cut map and FixedPointNormalize (adding hard edge between land and sea)", ha="center", size=14)
norm4 = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0, vmax=3400)
im4 = ax[1,0].imshow(data+1000, norm=norm4, cmap=cut_terrain_map)
fig.colorbar(im4, ax=ax[1,0])

norm5 = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0, vmax=3400)
im5 = ax[1,1].imshow(data, norm=norm5, cmap=cut_terrain_map)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im5, ax=ax[1,1])

norm6 = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0, vmax=0)
im6 = ax[1,2].imshow(data-2400.1, norm=norm6, cmap=cut_terrain_map)
fig.colorbar(im6, ax=ax[1,2])

for i, name in enumerate(["land only", "coast line", "sea only"]):
    for j in range(2):
        ax[j,i].text(0.96,0.96,name, ha="right", va="top", transform=ax[j,i].transAxes, color="w" )

plt.show()
```

[image]